# TFS Create branches from Main - selected changeset

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I have an issue; we have a Main branch, and we have few changesets (that belong to 3 different features).

I created three DEV branches By Date (and selected a date that is prior any of the changesets).
I cherry picked the changesets from Main, and merged them to appropriate DEV branches. 
I RolledBack all these changesets from Main so that, the main becomes clean.

Now I want to merge one of DEV branch to Main and deploy for testing, 
The problem is; it doesn't pick all the changesets, and even for the ones that it picks, it doesn't pick all the modified files.

How can I merge from DEV to Main? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When TFS does a merge, it bases the merge on prior merge history, not on the actual contents of the source and target files.

You could try the **/force** option with the tf merge command. The /force flag ignores merge history that indicates a particular changeset was previously merged from source to target (perhaps incorrectly), and merges the changeset again. You can do a /force merge for a single changeset or for a range of changesets. For just changeset #123456 the command would be:

```
tf merge /force $/Source/File.cs;C123456~123456 $/Target/file.cs
```

Check the following blog for more details:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/billheys/2011/03/16/my-source-and-target-files-are-different-but-merge-tells-me-there-are-no-changes-to-merge/